# renode, "push" a button and "see" a LED lighting

Tags: stm32, renode

I'm running my [first renode demo](https://renode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/demo.html), `stm32f4_discovery.resc`. So far so good, I see an announcement from Contiki in sysbus.uart4 window and Ethernet packets in the terminal.

How can I "push" the `UserButton` and "see" if `UserLED` is on?

`stm32f4_discovery.repl`:

```
UserButton: Miscellaneous.Button @ gpioPortA
    -> gpioPortA@0

UserLED: Miscellaneous.LED @ gpioPortD

gpioPortD:
    12 -> gpioPortD@0
```

The closest example I found so far was [I2C temperature](https://renode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic/environment.html#accessing-the-readings-of-a-sensor).

Are sources of the demo-.elf available somewhere?
http://antmicro.com/projects/renode/stm32f4discovery.elf-s_445441-and.so.on...

Comment: No [renode] tag available yet. @Piotr Zierhoffer, I'm sure you know the answer...

Comment: Unfortunately, mentions on SO do not work like that, so I didn't see the question. Writing the answer right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with the STM32F4 Discovery platform description in Renode, which is now fixed on master.

To toggle a button you should use the Monitor CLI. To list all available methods:

```
(STM32F4_Discovery) gpioPortA.UserButton 
The following methods are available:
[...]
 - Void Press ()
 - Void PressAndRelease ()
 - Void Release ()
[...]
 - Void Toggle ()
[...]
```

You can use these to interact with the button:

```
(STM32F4_Discovery) gpioPortA.UserButton Toggle
```

The LED state will be changed, but it's not very easy to spot. You can either check the state manually:

```
(STM32F4_Discovery) gpioPortA.externalLed State 
False (or True)
```

You can also track accesses to the LED in the logger window. To enable that, run:

```
(STM32F4_Discovery) logLevel -1 gpioPortA.externalLed 
(STM32F4_Discovery) logLevel 3 # this is not required, but will hush other logs
```

Unfortunately, the sources are not available - it's a very old demo and we didn't track them as well back then.